# how to setup octopress if you already have one in github?

Tags: jekyll, octopress, jekyll-bootstrap

this is my blog hosted in github.

http://john-qin.github.io/

now, i want to setup octopress on my ubuntu 12.04.  I followed the instruction on this page.
http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

I got stuck after "rake setup_github_pages". this instruction is for setting up brand new environment for octopress.  I already have it in github. how do I pull the existing one? and where should I put them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octopress repositories have two branches, *source* and *master*. The source branch contains the files that are used to generate the blog and the master contains the blog itself.

When the local folders are initially configured according to the Octopress Setup Guide, the master branch is stored in a subfolder named _*deploy*. Since the folder name begins with an underscore, it is ignored when you git push origin source. Instead, the master branch (which contains your blog posts) gets updated when you `rake deploy`.

To recreate the local directory structure of an existing Octopress blog, follow these instructions.

First you need to clone the source branch to the local octopress folder.

```
git clone -b source git@github.com:username/username.github.com.git octopress
```

Then clone the master branch to the _deploy subfolder.

```
cd octopress
git clone git@github.com:username/username.github.com.git _deploy
```

Then run the rake installation to configure everything

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash    # If you use rbenv, rehash to be able to run the bundle command
bundle install
rake setup_github_pages
```

It will prompt you for your repository URL. Enter the read/write url for your repository
(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com)

You now have a new local copy of your Octopress blog. Check out [this post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/) for more information.

Comment: ah! i don't have source branch , maybe because i never did `git push origin source`. What to do now?  I only have master branch.

Comment: I think you found your own answer and posted it on my blog. Thanks. If you have no source branch in your repo, create it before cloning from another system.

Comment: Yea ! But `rake deploy` should automatically create source branch. It's a disaster if a user loses source files .